# Importing a LESS file into a scope produces incorrect selector order

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I want to wrap the contents of a LESS file into a scope. The recent version of LESS supports this, but some selectors in the resulting CSS are out of expected order. I have identified that parent selectors standing at the end of expression cause this problem.

**3rd-party.less**

```css
.mixin() {
    .container > & {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
.class1 {
    width: 200px;
}
.class2 {
    .mixin();
}
```

**wrapped.less**

```css
.wrapper {
    @import "3rd-party.less";
}
```

Building **wrapped.less** produces the following CSS:

```css
.wrapper .class1 {
  width: 200px;
}
.container > ﻿.wrapper .class2 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

while I want to get this:

```css
.wrapper .class1 {
  width: 200px;
}
.wrapper .container > ﻿.class2 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Is it possible to get the desired result without modifying 
**3rd-party.less**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have achieved the correct selector order by building **3rd-party.less** and importing the result:

```css
.wrapper {
    @import (less) "3rd-party.css";
}
```

This solution produces an intermediate file, but the final output is exactly as expected.

Comment: This is the most random workaround, but it works fine. Seems like a bug with LESS.